# Null iterator end function?

Tags: c++, iterator

From what I understand, the end function of an iterator should return null. When I try to return nullptr, the program crashes. Can someone explain how the end function should behave?

**End()**

```
LinkList::Iterator LinkList::end()
{
    return tail->next;
}
```

**Update**

Here's my LinkList class. The other two are nested inside it.

**Class**

```
class LinkList
{
public:

class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    {
        next = prev = NULL;
    }
    Node(int num)
    {
        data = num; next = prev = NULL;
    }

    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator(Node* ptr);
    Iterator operator ++();
    int operator *();
    bool operator ==(Iterator it);
    bool operator !=(Iterator it);
    Node *ptr;
};

public:
    LinkList();
    virtual ~LinkList();
    LinkList(const LinkList& other);
    LinkList& operator=(LinkList& other);

    bool insert(int num);
    void insert(const initializer_list<int>& il);

    void merge(LinkList & src);
    Iterator *it;
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();

    int size();
    void clear();

private:
    Node *head, *tail, *temp;
    int count;
};
```

Comment: You understand wrong.

Comment: There are a lot of details missing here. Iterators are highly dependent on the container they are iterating over. I see a `LinkList` type, though. Hmm...

Comment: The `end()` function should return a valid iterator that represents *one past the end* of whatever elements it is iterating over.

Comment: It is for a doubly linked list.

Comment: @Deprecitus The `end()` function should return an iterator that points 1 off beyond the last valid element of the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The end function of an iterator may or may not return nullptr, it depends on your implementation. For example, the end() function of STL vectors "point to" the position after the last element of the vector.

From the code you provided, I can't say what is causing your program to crash, but my bet would be that when you call the end() function, "tail" is nullptr. Check if that is the case.

**EDIT:**

After seeing your class, I agree that your Iterator::end() function should return nullptr. In your implementation you return tail->next, which in fact should be nullptr, but if tail itself is nullptr (i.e., there are no nodes in your list), your program will crash because you are trying to access a member of an object that is null.
Just do:

```
LinkList::Iterator LinkList::end() {
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: After running gdb, the segmentation fault is due to tail returning nullptr. So, what should one after end look like?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes? The answer is correct? Don't judge from the OP's rep but the contents please.

Comment: @Deprecitus it depend on the implementation: if your linked list use ``nulltpr`` as sentinel for the end then you might want to return``nullptr``.

Comment: Thank you, @πάνταῥεῖ. Probably someone downvoted because I'm not being rigorous with the "point to" nomenclature, because iterators are not pointers although they usually act like it.

Comment: @Deprecitus If you provide the code from your iterator class, it would be easier to help you :) Your end() function really depends on your implementation

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Yeah, that was the problem.